# UDP multicasting not working

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8, udp

I am creating a WPF desktop application and Windows phone 8 app. The idea is to able to compose the SMS in Desktop application and send to Windows phone 8 app through UDP multicasting when they are in the same network.

In WP8, I have used SMSComposeTask to compose the SMS in phone. In desktop side I have used the code which I find in the link http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/. In Windows phone 8 app, I have followed the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286407(v=vs.105).aspx.

I am able to send the SMS messages to  WP8 emulators. But when I try to send the message to Windows phone device, I am not receiving any SMS message. I have the latest firmware in WP8 device. Already I have referred the link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-us/4eb2b9c1-5ada-422e-93a2-fbafe3a67491/udp-multicast-listener-not-working-on-wp8.

Is there any better way to communicate between Desktop application and Windows phone 8 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The network used for sending multicasting is Windows phone internal network. I changed the code from `udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);` to `IPAddress localAddress =IPAddress.Parse(GetIP());udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress,localAddress);` where GetIP function is

```
private string GetIP()
{
     string strHostName = "";

     strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

     IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

     IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

     return addr[addr.Length-1].ToString();

   }
```